# Is this a safe way to increase the current in a battery charger?

Tags: current, battery-charging, charger

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAy7qJTXWA8&ab_channel=AVGSolutions) and basically what he's doing is using the 4056 charger controller pin 7 to switch a IRF9540 that connects the positive straight through to the MOSFET.

Seems this would use the 4056 for all the protections and regulations, but higher current output.

I'd like to output ~2 A to the battery, but the chip on that board stops at 1 A. I've seen others change R3 to kick up the current to ~1.4 A but it was causing heat issues. This MOSFET idea could keep the chip cooler, plus you can adjust the amps based on the input.

I know that you can change the resistor as well as stack the boards for more amps, but this seems like an easy solution without heating up the chip because it bypasses the chip.

If I understand this, the current doesn't go through the 4056 chip on the board, the current to charge the battery bypasses that and only uses the chip for protection and switching.

Is this assessment correct?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNgm7.png)

[image: Ω]

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that setup to link the pics, but @2:00 in the video, there is a schematic.

Comment: YouTube videos are not good source material for a question as they often get moved or deleted. You need to post images or draw a schematic.

Comment: You need to either inline a schematic into your question via picture or you can draw a schematic by clicking Edit and then on the schematic symbol. Without a schematic, this question will most likely get closed as _unclear_. Schematics rule in the world of EE.

Comment: Will that work?

Comment: That’s a wiring diagram, not a schematic. Certainly a step in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not safe. It will short circuit the incoming 5V supply directly to the battery. Which is in no way an acceptable thing to do to charge lithium batteries.

It will also prevent the TP4056 from beasuring battery voltage and current properly, so it cannot determine when battery charging voltage is reached and when charging current has reached the level of terminating the charge of a full battery.

Mishandled and mischarged batteries degrade and damage, damaged batteries are a safety risk as they can explode or burst into flames.

Which may be the point of that video, the author may be trolling and telling deliberately how to make dangerous circuits to cause fires and damage when people replicate their curcuits, or just genuinely unaware of the risks.

Answer (score 1):

So the intention seems to be basically to support or **push** the charging with a "switchable" external resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAp8cX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The external resistor (PMOS) will be switched off via the CHG\ output of the TP4056 once the cell/battery voltage reaches the stop voltage, 4.2 VDC.

---

- The MOSFET's on-resistance is given as 0.2 Ohms for Vgs = -10V. In this mod the Vgs will be -5V so I assume an on-resistance of ~0.4 Ohms (pessimistic estimation).

The trick relies on using a CV/CC adapter. I watched the video muted (because I'm in the office) but if I understood correctly, the adapter is capable of limiting the output current at ~2 Amps. This can be seen at 8th minute of the video: The output is shunted with a resistor and the output voltage drops to ~0.5 VDC whilst the output current is kept at ~2 Amps.

Once the circuit is energised the TP4056 will start charging and turn the PMOS on with the \CHG output as the load voltage is less than 4.2 VDC. That will basically bypass the charger with the MOSFET's on-resistance (0.3 Ohms) and, presumably, bring a current of (5-3.8) / 0.4 = 3 A.

That will force the adapter to operate in CC mode, and the output voltage will be limited by the battery itself which is around 4 VDC. The battery voltage will quickly reach 4.2 VDC and then the TP4056 will turn the MOSFET off by the \CHG output.

Seems legit. However...

The biggest problem here is that not all batteries are happy with a charging current of 2 Amps. Also the battery's charging current should be reduced gradually after reaching some voltage level (~4 V in your case) to bring the least lifetime reduction and also for safety reasons. More importantly, the battery temperature will increase quickly which may result in explosion.

So no, the method is **unsafe**.

---

PS: The IRF9540 is a PMOS, not an NMOS. To be honest, I'd think twice before trying a so-called trick by someone who doesn't seem to be knowing what they are doing.

[image]